# Show that $f(x)=x^4$ is convex

Tags: functions

for $x\in (0,\infty)$ show $f(x)=x^4$ is convex. 
I know it is convex since $f''(x)>0$ 
. How can we show by using definition?
do we have to use 
Let L be linear space. $t\in[0,1],y\in L,f(xt+y(1-t))=(xt)^4+4(xt)^3((1-t)y)^1+6(xt)^2((1-t)y)^2+4(xt)(((1-t)y)^3+((1-t)y)^4$

edit:
$(xt)^4+4(xt)^3((1-t)y)^1+6(xt)^2((1-t)y)^2+4(xt)(((1-t)y)^3+((1-t)y)^4\le tf(x)+4tf(x)+10tf(x)(1-t)f(y)+(1-t)f(y)$

Comment: You need to add clarification. What is $L$?

Comment: Hint: $x^4 = (x^2)^2$ and $f(x) = x^2$ is convex and increasing on $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: Note $f''(x)\geq 0$ in general, not $>0$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580856/proof-of-convexity-of-fx-x2 Then use the Hint of Random Jack :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I know. thanks. @ RandomJack goint to try soon

Comment: @RandomJack I understand why $x^2$ is convex. is it true $((xt+(1-t)y)^2)^2\le (x^2t+(1-t)y^2)^2\le x^4t+(1-t)y^4+2(1-t)ty^2x^2$ how to continue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to show that $f(x) = x^2$ is convex and increasing on $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Hence $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}_+, t \in [0, 1]$ we have:

$$(tx + (1-t)y)^4 = ((tx + (1-t)y)^2)^2 \stackrel{(1)}\leqslant (tx^2 + (1-t)y^2)^2
\stackrel{(2)}\leqslant \\ t(x^2)^2 + (1-t)(y^2)^2 = tx^4 + (1-t)y^4.$$

$(1)$: using that $x^2$ is convex and increasing.

$(2)$: again using that $x^2$ is convex.

Note also that in your question $L = \mathbb{R}_+$. This is not a linear space and it should not be. But it must be convex because we can speak about convexity of a function only on a convex subset of its domain.

Answer (score 4):

Note that by definition a function is convex in a domain when for any two points in the domain, the value of the linear interpolation between those two points for a third point in between them is greater than the value of the function at that third point. The idea is[image]
Now all you have to check is that for any ${x_{\rm{i}}} > 0
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaaiabdIha4naaBaaaleaacqqGPbqA
% aeqaaOGaeyOpa4JaeGimaadaaa!43FD!
$ and ${x_{\rm{f}}} > {x_{\rm{i}}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaaiabdIha4naaBaaaleaacqqGMbGz
% aeqaaOGaeyOpa4JaemiEaG3aaSbaaSqaaiabbMgaPbqabaaaaa!4607!
$ and $\xi  = (1 - t){x_{\rm{i}}} + t{x_{\rm{f}}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaaiabe67a4jabg2da9iabcIcaOiab
% igdaXiabgkHiTiabdsha0jabcMcaPiabdIha4naaBaaaleaacqqGPb
% qAaeqaaOGaey4kaSIaemiDaqNaemiEaG3aaSbaaSqaaiabbAgaMbqa
% baaaaa!4F1B!
$ (such that $0 < t < 1
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaaiabicdaWiabgYda8iabdsha0jab
% gYda8iabigdaXaaa!4456!
$), $$f({x_{\rm{i}}}) + \frac{{f({x_{\rm{f}}}) - f({x_{\rm{i}}})}}{{{x_{\rm{f}}} - {x_{\rm{i}}}}}(\xi  - {x_{\rm{i}}}) > f(\xi )
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaaiabdAgaMjabcIcaOiabdIha4naa
% BaaaleaacqqGPbqAaeqaaOGaeiykaKIaey4kaSYaaSaaaeaacqWGMb
% GzcqGGOaakcqWG4baEdaWgaaWcbaGaeeOzaygabeaakiabcMcaPiab
% gkHiTiabdAgaMjabcIcaOiabdIha4naaBaaaleaacqqGPbqAaeqaaO
% GaeiykaKcabaGaemiEaG3aaSbaaSqaaiabbAgaMbqabaGccqGHsisl
% cqWG4baEdaWgaaWcbaGaeeyAaKgabeaaaaGccqGGOaakcqaH+oaEcq
% GHsislcqWG4baEdaWgaaWcbaGaeeyAaKgabeaakiabcMcaPiabg6da
% +iabdAgaMjabcIcaOiabe67a4jabcMcaPaaa!6738!
$$. Replacing the function that you have asked yields proving that $${x_{\rm{f}}}^4 - ((1 - t){x_{\rm{i}}}^4 + t{x_{\rm{f}}}^4) + t({x_{\rm{f}}}^4 - {x_{\rm{i}}}^4) > 0
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaaiabdIha4naaBaaaleaacqqGMbGz
% aeqaaOWaaWbaaSqabeaacqaI0aanaaGccqGHsislcqGGOaakcqGGOa
% akcqaIXaqmcqGHsislcqWG0baDcqGGPaqkcqWG4baEdaWgaaWcbaGa
% eeyAaKgabeaakmaaCaaaleqabaGaeGinaqdaaOGaey4kaSIaemiDaq
% NaemiEaG3aaSbaaSqaaiabbAgaMbqabaGcdaahaaWcbeqaaiabisda
% 0aaakiabcMcaPiabgUcaRiabdsha0jabcIcaOiabdIha4naaBaaale
% aacqqGMbGzaeqaaOWaaWbaaSqabeaacqaI0aanaaGccqGHsislcqWG
% 4baEdaWgaaWcbaGaeeyAaKgabeaakmaaCaaaleqabaGaeGinaqdaaO
% GaeiykaKIaeyOpa4JaeGimaadaaa!64D0!
$$. Note that the above inequality is trivially true when the domain is restricted to the positive real line, so the function is convex indeed.